How to properly mock HttpContextAccessor with Request.Form for controller testing in .NET 6
I have the following code for mocking the HttpContextAccessor. Most of it works fine but the area that I can't get to work as expected is getting form values, specifically when trying to get them while iterating over the Keys collection.
I put a breakpoint on the AddFormFieldsOrFile method where it creates the new requestForm, and when I mouse over that, it shows me an object with properties like Count, Keys, and Store and it has the values I added to it.

But if I put a breakpoint on the code where it's iterating over the keys and look at the Request.Form mock, it looks different. The Store property is gone and I don't see how to access the values based on the key.

If I let it continue, the value comes back as an empty string. So, I'm assuming I am not setting up the requestForm mock correctly.
public class MockHttpContextAccessor
{
    public Mock<IHttpContextAccessor> ContextAccessor { get; private set; }
    private FormFileCollection fileCollection;
    private FormCollection requestForm;
    private List<string> keys = new List<string>();

    public MockHttpContextAccessor()
    {
        var requestFeature = new HttpRequestFeature();
        var features = new FeatureCollection();

        features.Set<IHttpRequestFeature>(requestFeature);
        ContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var session = new MockHttpSession();
        var context = new DefaultHttpContext(features);
        
        fileCollection = new FormFileCollection();
        requestForm = new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues>(), fileCollection);
        
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(context);
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Session).Returns(session);
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Path).Returns("/path");
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Form).Returns(requestForm);
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files).Returns(requestForm.Files);
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys).Returns(keys);
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Headers).Returns(new Mock<IHeaderDictionary>().Object);
    }

    public void AddRequestBody(string content)
    {
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Body).Returns(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)));
    }

    public void AddQueryStringParameters(Dictionary<string, string> p)
    {
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.QueryString).Returns(new QueryString("?" + string.Join("&", p.Select(x => $"{x.Key}={x.Value}"))));
    }

    public void ClearQueryStringParameters()
    {
        ContextAccessor
            .Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.QueryString)
            .Returns(new QueryString("?"));
    }

    public void SetDefaultFileUpload(string content = "some content", string filename = "filename.pdf", string formFieldID = "id_from_form")
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        IFormFile file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, formFieldID, filename);

        var formContents = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();
        AddFormFieldsOrFile(formContents, new List<IFormFile> { file });
    }
    
    public void AddFormFieldsOrFile(Dictionary<string, StringValues> fields, List<IFormFile> files = null)
    {
        if (files != null && files.Any())
        {
            ContextAccessor.Object.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            fileCollection.AddRange(files);
        }

        requestForm = new FormCollection(fields, fileCollection);
        
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            keys.Add(field.Key);
        }
    }

    public void ClearFormFiles()
    {
        fileCollection.Clear();
    }
}

Here's how I'm setting it up in my test.
[SetUp]
public override async Task SetUp()
{
    _httpContextAccessor.AddFormFieldsOrFile(new Dictionary<string, StringValues>()
    {
        {"workingWithAgency", new StringValues("66199")}
    });
    await base.SetUp();
}

And finally, the code that I'm trying to test.
private List<SpecifiedByRecord> getFormFieldContacts(string name)
{
    var retval = new List<SpecifiedByRecord>();

    foreach (var key in _context.Request.Form.Keys)
        if (key.Contains(name))
        {
            var val = _context.Request.Form[key].ToString();
            var els = val.Split('^');
            retval.Add(new SpecifiedByRecord {Id = els[0], Name = els[1]});
        }

    return retval;
}


Does this answer your question? Mock IHttpContextAccessor in Unit Tests

@roten I don't know if you lack the reps or you don't know it: you can click on "close", then "Duplicate", then specify the duplicate you think it is.

It's not a duplicate.  I'm asking about setting up the request form fields and accessing them.  The suggested link doesn't touch on that.  And I'm already using the DefaultHttpContext in my setup so it goes beyond that.

@geoffswartz I removed my original comment - not to be sneaky, it was just plain stupid.

In your MockHttpContextAccessor() constructor you do the following:
        var context = new DefaultHttpContext(features);
        
        fileCollection = new FormFileCollection();
        requestForm = new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues>(), fileCollection);
        
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(context);

You set your Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>.HttpContext to return the DefaultHttpContext.
However; with the following statement you are overriding the call to this object
ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Form).Returns(requestForm);
I think you can just do something along the line of this:
{
        ..
        var context = new DefaultHttpContext(features);

        _fileCollection = new FormFileCollection();
        requestForm = new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues>(), _fileCollection);
        context.Request.Form = requestForm;

        ContextAccessor.Setup(_ => _.HttpContext).Returns(context);
}


I'm getting the same behavior if I do that.

Did you remove all of your other ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.[..] setups?  I had it working on my end using your provided code

I did.  But I just went through creating a simple project to see if it worked there and sure enough it did.  Even my original implementation worked.  So, there's something going on elsewhere that's throwing this off.  Now to find out what it is.  Thanks for the help.
